# How to select next item in data validation list item without vba

Tags: excel, validation

I have created an excel worksheet that contains a Data Validation List that populates it's entries from a Table located on another sheet within the same workbook. The list updates as it is meant to as I manipulate the data in the table. So I have no issue with that.

What I am looking to do is select either the next or the previous entry in the validation list using the keyboard (for example the up or down arrows). Is there a way to do this without using VBA?

The page that contains the Data Validation list is completely locked except for the cell that contains the Validation List. I have also scroll locked the page so that Page Up and Page Down don't work.

I am hoping there is a way not using VBA as the file will be shared with other people in my office that use iOS laptops that won't allow scripts to run in the file, even when the file is located on the Company Cloud. I am the only one on a Windows device.

Any help with be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No sooner had I posted the question than I figured it out. So here is the answer if anyone needs it.
While the Cell is selected, press and hold down the "ALT" button, then the "DOWN or UP ARROW"
Then release the ALT and continue to move the cursor with the Up and Down Arrows. Press ENTER to select the entry you want.